# How do I set the selected item in the SelectList of a DropDownFor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to MVC, but I've read through several questions on this topic. None of the answers fix my problem, though. Here's my code (just the pertinent properties):

**C# Classes**

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; internal set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Project
{
    public int ProjectId { get; internal set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public Customer CurrentCustomer { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller Class**

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    Project item = projectRepository.Get(id);

    ViewBag.AllCustomers = new SelectList(
        new CustomerRepository().Get(), // Returns a List<Customer> of all active customers.
        "CustomerId",
        "Name",
        (object) item.CurrentCustomer.CustomerId);

    return View(item);
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CurrentCustomer)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CurrentCustomer, (SelectList)ViewBag.AllCustomers, "-- Select a Customer. --")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CurrentCustomer)
</div>
```

I've tried this without using the ViewBag (doing the SelectList instantiation in the View itself), which also didn't work. I've tried hard-coding an ID instead of using CurrentCustomer.CustomerId, but when I set a breakpoint on the SelectList itself, I see that it's handling everything correctly.

All of the other StackOverflow questions suggest that the above method and property names should work just fine, but for the life of me I cannot figure out what's wrong here. What am I missing?

Comment: Looks like your `Casting` is backwards  shouldn't it be more like this 
`@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CurrentCustomer, ViewBag.AllCustomer as SelectList...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you are using *EF Code-First*. The  mistake you are making is trying to assign an int (id) to an entity `CurrentCustomer`. The `dropdownlist` only returns an id not an entity.

You should send an Id to your action method, then find and assign the entity (or arguably just the foreign key)

**In your model add an Id**

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjectId { get; internal set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public Customer CurrentCustomer { get; set; }
    public int CurrentCustomerId { get; set; }
}
```

**In your View**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CurrentCustomerId,
 (SelectList)ViewBag.AllCustomers, "-- Select a Customer. --")
```

Comment: Ah, I see! Let me update my class and test. I never put those two together when I went through the examples here.

Comment: Yep -- that was exactly it. Great catch!